# Why is my local MongoDB opening so many connections?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, next.js, homebrew

I am using this for my initial connection

```
let cachedDb: Db

export async function connectToDatabase(): Promise<{ db: Db }> {
  if (cachedDb) {
    return { db: cachedDb }
  }

  const client = await MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URI)
  const db = client.db(MONGODB_DB)
  cachedDb = db

  return { db }
}
```

and calling it like this

```
  const { db } = await connectToDatabase()
  const models_collection = db.collection("models")
```

I am using a MongoDB installed with brew

The same code doesn't open connections if the app and the mongodb are running on 2 servers

Logs

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-11T14:06:57.523+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn55","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:62817","client":"conn55","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs","version":"5.6.0"},"platform":"Node.js v16.20.0, LE","os":{"name":"darwin","architecture":"arm64","version":"22.4.0","type":"Darwin"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-11T14:07:02.938+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:62818","uuid":"269dbd97-1a91-4c2a-bbdc-8313b3baa074","connectionId":56,"connectionCount":25}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-11T14:07:02.939+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:62819","uuid":"f5d98157-90d1-44dc-8ded-87cb02372cac","connectionId":57,"connectionCount":26}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-11T14:07:02.939+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:62820","uuid":"373ad014-2138-4a50-a150-36ea1585999f","connectionId":58,"connectionCount":27}}
```

I tried to restructure the code and set some connection params, but nothing did work

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to problem with the way you check for cache here:

`const client = await MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URI)` is an asynchronous operation, and if the `connectToDatabase()` is called multiple times before this operation ended then you will try to open multiple connections and will then cache latest one.

You can change the code to cache promise instead.

```js
let cachedDb: Promise<Db>

export async function connectToDatabase(): Promise<{ db: Db }> {
  if (!cachedDb) {
    // we can use promises to avoid creating extra function
    // cahcedDb = MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URI).then(client => client.db(MONGO_DB));
    async function getDb() {
      const client = await MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URI)
      return client.db(MONGODB_DB)
    }

    cachedDb = getDb();
  }

  return { db: await cachedDb }
}
```

Comment: It still opens connections up to the threshold where mongodb tells me that there are too many connections